# how to i use check button to show the snap

Tags: python, tkinter

**My program is designed to:**

- Initially, the Label shows nothing (i.e., it is empty).
- Any number of the Checkbuttons may be selected by the user.
- Any selected Checkbuttons may be unselected by the user.
- When any two Checkbuttons are selected, the Label shows "Snap".
- When any other number of Checkbuttons is selected, the Label shows
  nothing (i.e., it is empty).

**This is my code, so far**

```
display = ScrolledText(the_window,font=('Arial',24),width =10,height =2,
                       borderwidth=2,relief='groove')
display.place(x=80,y=7)

def display_snap():
    display.insert(END,'Snap')
    if display_snap

checkbox = Checkbutton(the_window,command = display_snap)
checkbox.place(x=10,y=80)

checkbox2 = Checkbutton(the_window)
checkbox2.place(x=60 , y=80)

checkbox3 = Checkbutton(the_window)
checkbox3.place(x=110 , y=80)

checkbox4 = Checkbutton(the_window)
checkbox4.place(x=160 , y=80)

checkbox5 = Checkbutton(the_window)
checkbox5.place(x=210 , y=80)
```

Comment: It all depends on your CheckButton class. What library do you use? I guess you are missing a tag to indicate this.

Comment: What problem are you having? Have you read the documentation for the Checkbutton widget to learn how to associate the checkbutton with a variable?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using Tkinter. As the [Tkinter docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) say "each Checkbutton widget should be associated with a variable". You can detect whether the widget is selected or not by using the `.get()` method of the variable: a value of 0 means the button is unselected, 1 means it's selected.

Here's a simple program that stores the buttons' variables in a list. We can then use the built-in `sum` function to count how many buttons are selected, and update the text of the Label widget accordingly.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='')
label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

def set_snap():
    text = 'Snap' if sum(v.get() for v in states) == 2 else ''
    label.config(text=text)

states = []
for i in range(5):
    var = tk.IntVar()
    states.append(var)
    cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var, command=set_snap)
    cb.grid(row=1, column=i)

root.mainloop()
```

The above code is for Python 3. To run it on Python 2, just change the `import` line to

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: tnks a lot but final i can't When any other number of Checkbuttons is selected, the Label shows nothing how to i solve it ?

Comment: @KhorTerence: Sorry, I don't understand. In the question you said: "When any two Checkbuttons are selected, the Label shows 'Snap'. When any other number of Checkbuttons is selected, the Label shows nothing." And that's _exactly_ what my program does.

Comment: kook just now i solve it already thanks for you help me and the code very thanks a lot